# ¿Como multiplicar dos valores en c#?

Tags: c#

Tengo este dato que lo traigo desde la BD en el cual se aloja en ese `preciototal.Text` que es el nombre de un control `Label`.

Bien, lo que quiero es saber como multiplico ese valor con otra variable tipo entero que tengo reservada llamada `int Days`. Para explicarlo mejor,quiero llamar ese valor entero que hay en la BD y multiplicarlo con la variable entera `Days`.

Quisiera hacer algo como `Int resultado = Days * preciototal;`

```
 preciototal.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Precioxdia"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo logré:

```
 int days = 10;
 int valorBD = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["Precioxdia"]);
        int multip = valorBD * days;

        string result= Convert.ToString(multip);
        Label1.Text = result;
```

Comment: Ten cuidado con el Convert ya que si no puede hacerlo te dará una exepcion y si no la controladas petara el flujo. Puede ser que en este caso no haya nunca un valor erróneo pero siempre hay que prevenir.                                                                         Ejemplo: El campo que viene de la BD sea **null**

Comment: @Rosca Descuida,ese campo nunca estará vacío en mi BD. Es tan necesario como el ID de cada registro.

Answer (score 1):

```
int days = 5;
        int precioTotal;

        string precio = "200";

        if (int.TryParse(precio, out precioTotal))
        {
            int resultado = days * precioTotal;
        }
```

Con el tryParse puedes comprobar que se puede convertir a entero en este caso puedes cambiar **int** por **double** y intentar convertirlo a double.

Answer (score 0):

Debes convertir a número los valores que quieres multiplicar para que la operación se efectue correctamente.

Podría funcionarte algo parecido a esto:

```
double resultado = (Convert.ToDouble(preciototal.Text) * Days);
```

Comment: Amigo,como hago para que en vez de tener guardado el resultado en el Label,osea no lo quiero asignado directamente al hacer la consulta,sino que lo guarde en una variable.